# Is it necessary to upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

we are currently using 2.3.3 . I it necessary to upgrade the version 2.3.x to  2.4.x or we can keep using 2.3.x ? can anyone explain it a bit

thank you

Comment: Both 2.3.x and 2.4.x are being maintained by Magento currently. While 2.4.x offers additional features, all of the security updates are being added with 2.3.x. It's not entirely necessary to upgrade to 2.4.x just yet as long as you're keeping up with the security updates

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: @A.Fletcher check my answer below :) at some point it will be entirely necessary to upgrade to 2.4.x :)

Answer (score 8):

Well, you could upgrade to 2.3.7, but eventually **your application will fall behind with regards to compatibility with the latest versions of services like PHP, MySQL, etc**. Take a look here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html and you will see for example that 2.4.x supports Mysql 8.0 and 2.3.x only 5.7, or that Magento 2.4.5 will support PHP 8.1, but the 2.3.7 supports only 7.4.

In addition to this, as per [the lifecycle policy documentation](https://magento.com/sites/default/files/magento-software-lifecycle-policy.pdf):
[image]which means that **starting April 2022, all 2.3.x installations will no longer be supported** and no security patches will be provided for them, which in turn, means that your application will become vulnerable to security issues.

Also, from another notice seen on the devdocs pages:
[image]

**Moreover, staying on 2.3.x means that you will not benefit of the latest fixes and improvements of the core functionalities or new features that are launched with the 2.4.x version.** I find that this article https://blog.magezon.com/magento-2-4-vs-2-3-a-complete-comparison/ sums it up pretty well and you can also check the [official release notes for 2.4.x](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html) to make an idea of which are your benefits if you upgrade to this version.

Comment: thank you @Diana for such a great explanation

Comment: You are most welcome! Please consider marking this answer as solution to your question of it provided the information you were looking for, so others can benefit from it too. Good luck!