# How to make choice a between 2.3.7 and 2.4, current 2.3.3?

Tags: upgrade, stores, version

We are planning to upgrade our store, the current version is 2.3.3, but which version should we choose, 2.4.* or 2.3.7? Is there an LTS version?

Answer (score 1):

For long term support it's best to upgrade directly to the latest version (2.4.2-p1), as 2.3.x will reach end of life in April 2022.

A note from the 2.3.7 release notes:

> PHP 7.3 reaches end of support in December 2021, and Adobe Commerce
> 2.3.x reaches end of support in April 2022. We strongly recommend planning your upgrade now to Adobe Commerce 2.4.x and PHP 7.4.x to
> help maintain PCI compliance.

Comment: the support deadline is a sufficient reason to version 2.4.*

Answer (score 0):

For a deeper understanding of the matter, please check my answer in this thread [Is it necessary to upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337128/is-it-necessary-to-upgrade-from-2-3-to-2-4/337133#337133), it's more than just keeping up to date with the latest versions of the services, it's also about benefiting of the latest functionalities present in 2.4 which you won't find in 2.3

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For long term comparability with Magnento 2 and PHP it is better to upgrade to later version, eventually you will need to do better sooner rather than later, I will say go to 2.4.2

Unless 2.4 is long stretch for you and team better to go directly to 2.4( We were having similar considerations ) what we had done is asked one dedicated developer to try existing custom modules on 2.4 First and checked core functionality.

Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course magento 2.4.x will better than 2.3.7 because with 2.4.x magento have more features such as elasticsearch but magento 2.4.x is difficult to deploy.